# Angular - how to stop using hash links to navigate?

Tags: angularjs, navigation

Bear with me, I'm new to Angular.

I used the yeoman angular generator to scaffold a project. I've got this in my navigation:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
      <li class="active"><a ng-href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a></li>
      <li><a ng-href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I don't like having the hashes in there, because when the site goes live, I don't want links to look like `http://example.com/#/about`. But if I change the above to:

```
<a ng-href="/about">About</a></li>
```

The page breaks when I try to hit the About page. Here's what's in app.js:

```
angular
  .module('wowApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure `$locationProvider` to enable HTML5 mode.

```
angular
    .module('wowApp', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngTouch'
    ])
    .config([
        '$locationProvider',
        '$routeProvider',
        function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
            // Set HTML 5 mode to true to disable #
            // in push states
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            // Setting HTML5 mode to true also requires
            // you to set a base URL for the application
            // or disable `requireBase`. If you don't need base
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled : true,
                requireBase : false
            });


            $routeProvider.when(/* route logic as normal */);    
        }
    ]);
```

[Reference for **$locationProvider**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider)

Now you can remove the #'s from your anchors href values.

Comment: Doesn't work. I get an error that says `$locationProvider.html5mode` is not a function. Also, are you missing a comma after `'$routeProvider'`?

Comment: Yes I was, fixed. Also it is `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` that is also fixed.

Comment: Okay, so when navigating the site, the hashes are gone. But if I take a URL like `http://example.com/about` and just paste it into a new browser, it obviously doesn't find the file because it doesn't exist. This is my problem. How can people link to specific pages of my site if they're not "real"?

Comment: `$routeProvider.otherwise()` as a fallback or return a pretty 404 from the server?

Comment: Why would I want to return a 404? If a user visits `http://example.com` and hits the "About" link, and is taken to `http://example.com/about`, they would expect to be able to email that link to someone. But in Angular, the link would break.

Comment: Yes... so when writing SPA's you need to make sure all your routes used in the front end actually load your application when navigated to manually. And you're right, that is a separate question ;-)

Comment: Aha. From the official Angular documentation on `$location`: Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html). Requiring a <base> tag is also important for this case, as it allows Angular to differentiate between the part of the url that is the application base and the path that should be handled by the application.

Comment: So I have to use Apache rewrites, so `/about` gets rewritten as `/#/about`

Comment: Very true on both counts. The server will need to do exactly as you say, using frameworks like Laravel (my opinion only) make this process very easy. And yes, the `<base>` tag is useful when your SPA is not located at `/` but in a nested structure.

Comment: Cool. Your answer was helpful, and this discussion also pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!